# "C:\Users\" it is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file

Tags: cmd, yarnpkg

Can you help me?
[Where's the problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIJRn.jpg)

Comment: Click the link for the question+

Comment: [Having white spaces in your Windows username fails the "create" command](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6630)

Comment: people won't click any links for the question. You need to include your code (as text) and necessary things in the question itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the space in your username. Try to install yarn in another place outside your home folder.

A piece of advice, create a new user without the spaces. The spaces in the user name will hurt you for the rest of your life.

Regards